# How can I retrieve the style of a class if I got nothing but the class name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is the css code:

```
# skin.css
.my_class {
  attr1: value1;
  attr2: value2;
}
```

I want to retrieve this properties, but `$(".my_class")` doesn't work becase I have no element with class `my_class` in my `DOM`. Is there anyway of achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a hidden DOM element, and append it to the body, then delete it:

```
$('<div class="my_class" style="display: none;"></div>').appendTo("body").css("attr1"); // => value1
```

You'd have to do something a bit differently if you cared about the `display` property, e.g. use `opacity` or `visibility` or `position: absolute; top: -100000px;`.

Comment: If you don't append it, it also won't be styled, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uTcPD/

Comment: I think display:hidden may cause flow issues that display:none would avoid. I wonder if there's a less hacky solution, though.

Comment: Thanks ChessWiz, fixed that too; dunno where my brain is today.

Comment: @ChessWhiz - There is no `display: hidden;` ;) There's a `visibility: hidden;` though.

Comment: @Nick I wrote `display: none`, which I believe exists. One of us is confused?

Comment: @ChessWhiz - "I think display:hidden may cause flow issues that display:none would avoid" :)

Comment: @Nick Haha, you got me. Yes, I meant `visibility:hidden`, which Domenic has now edited out of his answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a fake DOM element, make it invisible, add it to the page, and then read the css values. The downside is that you can't retrieve the `display` part of the style, but perhaps you don't need that.

```
$('<div class="my_class" style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body').css("attr1");
```

Here's a demo (based on Nick's fiddle): http://www.jsfiddle.net/uTcPD/1/